# Python: Problem with logging.error(traceback.format_exception)

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6, python-unittest

I have following code:

```
 def tearDown(self):
    e_type, e_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    if e_type is not None:
        logging.error((traceback.format_exception(e_type, e_value, tb)))
```

when I used Python 2.7 everything works fine, but after upgrade to version 3.6 it doesn't work anymore:

For example I have created some example for testing and I expect error.

```
def test_create_new_user_without_all_fields1(self):
    self.assertEqual('USER_1', 'USER_2')
    logging.info('test_create_new_user_without_all_fields1: Passed')
```

Result in console:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_new_user_without_all_fields1 (test_testExample.BaseTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\git\CST\tests\test_testExample.py", line 16, in test_create_new_user_without_all_fields1
    self.assertEqual('USER_1', 'USER_2')
AssertionError: 'USER_1' != 'USER_2'
- USER_1
+ USER_2
?  +
```

lets add small print to tearDown:

```
print (sys.exc_info())
```

Result:

```
(None, None, None)
```

As can we see there is no exceptions anymore, but should be. How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
e_type, e_value, tb = self._outcome.errors[1][1]
logging.error(''.join(traceback.format_exception(e_type, e_value, tb)))
```